# Strange problem with Phantomjs, it gets 404 error for an url, and it works fine for many other websites

Tags: linux, debian, php

I have Phantomjs 2.1.1 installed in debian 9, it works fine for many websites but it gets 404 error for this simple URL: http://writeastory.net/test.jpg

I tested in two servers, i got the same issue, can someone test this url if it works with your phantomjs? `http://writeastory.net/test.jpg`

> $source = 'http://My_URL/print.php'; 
>    $id = $_GET['id'];
>   $pg = $_GET['pg'];
>   page.open("' . $source . '?id=' . $id . '&pg=' . $pg . '", function(status) {
>     console.log("Status: " + status);
>     if(status === "success") {
>       page.render("uploads/' . $id . '/page' . $pg . '.jpg", {format: "jpeg", quality: "100"});
>     }
>     phantom.exit();
>   });
>   ';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because the IPV6 of the domain! when i disabled the IPV6 of writeastory.net, Phantomjs script is able now to capture the website.
So probably Phantomjs is not working well with IPV6 domain name.